# How do I fully type out this factorial function?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

`const fact: (n: number) => number = ((f: any) => f(f))((g: any) => (n : number) => n > 0 ? n * g(g)(n - 1) : 1);`

I started playing with Typescript yesterday, and my mind breaks just trying. n is obviously number, but what about f and g?

Comment: You can use interface to define what are the parameters/types of f and g, right now its any, but compile might also complain if you try to pass anything but function anyway; however, that might depend on your compiler settings.

Comment: The calls `f(f)` and `g(g)` suggest that those variables have a [recursive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). Does TypeScript support these?

Comment: @Bergi yes it does, you can have recursive interfaces, and interfaces can have call signatures, so you can have a function that accepts itself as a parameter.

Comment: @Bergi Seems so. I was making a linked list and `interface Node<V> { value: V, next: Node<V> }` works fine. Not sure if/how that can be used in functions.

Comment: @Artikash you can just define an interface with a call signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a callable interface that accepts itself as an argument and returns a result:

```
interface Rec<T> {
    (p: Rec<T>): T
}

const fact: (n: number) => number = ((f: Rec<(n: number)=> number>) => f(f))((g) => (n : number) => n > 0 ? n * g(g)(n - 1) : 1);
```

**Note** The compiler will infer the type of `g` to be `Rec<(n: number)=> number>`

Or a less generic and letting the compiler infer all it can version:

```
interface Rec {
    (p: Rec): (n: number)=> number
}

const fact = ((f: Rec) => f(f))((g) => (n) => n > 0 ? n * g(g)(n - 1) : 1);
```

Comment: Nice, works perfectly! Worth noting imo is that g is same type as f (`g: Rec<(n: number) => number>`)

Comment: @Artikash Yes, that's true, but the compiler can figure out all the types if you just type `f` as `Rec<(n: number)=> number>` and I usually let it do so. But you are right it should be pointed out :)